# Photoshop: edit closed stroke path

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path

I have drawn my shape with the pen tool and then closed the path with connecting first point to last point. There is a mistake and I need to edit the stroke path. When I move the pen cursor on a anchor point, a minus will be appear near the pen icon and then clicking on that point just deletes that point and does not open stroke path. I need to open where I had mistake and edit that area.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the direct selection tool, not the pen tool

[image]

Then select your anchor point, you can move it, or delete it (it will "open" your path)

[image: gif]

Comment: that not work because the path is closed. i have tested that. just moving whole all path

Comment: Maybe you picked the non-direct selection tool (black arrow).  Are you sure you picked the Direct selection tool (white arrow)?

Comment: yes. white one. may you make a gif tutorial?

Comment: see edited answer